# How to program a RPG game in C++ with SDL?

Tags: c++, sdl

I want to know how to program a 2D RPG game in C++ with SDL.

I have searched, but was unable to find anything good. Many of the articles were too basic and didn't delve into anything practical. Can anyone help give me some articles, free books or other resources so I can learn how to program a RPG using C++ and SDL?

EDIT:

I don't need documentation of SDL. I'm programming a RPG Game with SDL, and I need some examples that help me in this task.

Comment: What is your current hangup, or thing you are confused about?

Libsdl and C/C++ are both extremely well documented online and in real books.

Comment: Yeah, more information here would be a help. It's cool to know you are working on a 2D RPG, but unless that is part of what's holding you back then it's pretty much irrelevant. If you only need help in the SDL end, then Lieven's response is a great start. Long story short: please clarify.

Comment: Honestly if you aren't comfortable with programming, I might refer you to the program called RPGMaker, which lets you build a basic 2D RPG using a simple GUI.

Comment: Also if you're not comfortable with programming--skip C++.  There is virtually no point any more and it's a low enough level language that it will cause you no end of frustration and then you'll give up.  Try C#, java or something higher (flash/silverlight/fx???)

Comment: @Bill If the OP is hoping to get into the games industry, than C++ is a must, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have examples of articles that are too simple?

Are these too simple: [devshed](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Multimedia/Game-Programming-using-SDL-Getting-Started/) or [gpwiki](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/C:SDL_tutorials) ?

You might consider studying the topics separately. For example Bruce Eckels has, IMO, the best C++ books, "Thinking in C++ I & II" that will take you from novice to expert (including SQA techniques like unit testing) and they are available for [free.](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html)

I've found that C++ is a harsh mistress and if you aren't prepared for the language, no tutorial specific to 'SDL and Games' will help much - this is true for any other advanced libraries, toolkits, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Programming an RPG game isn't any different than programming any other game.

If you understand RPG's and you have a fully formed idea of what you want to do, then you use the same techniques that you would use working on any game.

Google is your friend here, use it to do the research to gain the skills you need.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [gamedev.net](http://gamedev.net)? They have articles and tutorials for all ability levels, as well as active forums filled with helpful people.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.libsdl.org/intro.en/toc.html

http://www.libsdl.org/tutorials.php

http://www.libsdl.org/articles.php

http://www.libsdl.org/books.php

Answer (score 1):

You can find a tutorial that shows you how to create an adventure game using ActionScript [here](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/blog/archive/2009/11/22/create-your-own-flash-adventure-game.aspx). While it is not SDL/C++ related, the general concepts should be easy to port across, or at the very least give you some idea on where to start.

[image]